# How to access textStatus outside ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to access textStatus after ajax.now i want to check this variable in if condition anyone help me
$this->registerJs("colorArray = ['#ff4c4c','#32CD32'];

```
    $('.grooveTable').on('click','td', function(){
    color = $(this).data('color') == undefined ? 0 : $(this).data('color')*2;

        // Get Url Parameter

        var result = [];
        window.location.search.replace(/[?&amp;]+([^=&amp;]+)=([^&amp;]*)/gi, 
        function(str, key, value) {
            result[key] = value;
        });

    $.ajax({
    url: '" . yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("area-chart/change-area-status") . "',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {areaCodeId : $(this).attr('id'),colourCode:color, location:result['tion%5D'],
    company_code:result['ny_code%5D'],division_code:result['rt%5Bdivision_code%5D']},
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    statusCheck = data;
    drawChart(data.idCompleted, data.idPending, data.idStarted);
    },});

        if(textStatus == 'SUCCESS' && color == undefined || color == colorArray.length ){

                $(this).css('background-color',colorArray[0]);
                $(this).data('color','0');

        }else if(textStatus == 'SUCCESS' == 'UPDATE'){

                $(this).css('background-color',colorArray[color+1]);
                $(this).data('color',color+1);

        }
```

});");

Comment: Don't think "outside ajax". Think "after ajax".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: sir very urgent help me.now am stuck

Comment: Because `textStatus` it doesn't exist outisde `$.ajax` success function scope.

Answer (score 2):

ajax is async.
just pass the parameter to your functions

```
$.ajax({
    url: '" . yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("area-chart/change-area-status") . "',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
        areaCodeId: $(this).attr('id'), colourCode: color, location: result['tion%5D'],
        company_code: result['ny_code%5D'], division_code: result['rt%5Bdivision_code%5D']
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        drawChart(data.idCompleted, data.idPending, data.idStarted);
        doSomething(textStatus);
    },
});


function doSomething(textStatus){
    if(textStatus == 'SUCCESS' && color == undefined || color == colorArray.length ){

        $(this).css('background-color',colorArray[0]);
        $(this).data('color','0');

    }else if(textStatus == 'SUCCESS'){

        $(this).css('background-color',colorArray[color+1]);
        $(this).data('color',color+1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
   $.ajax({
  url: '" . yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("area-chart/change-area-status") . "',
  dataType: 'json',
  method: 'GET',
  data: {
    areaCodeId: $(this).attr('id'),
    colourCode: color,
    location: result['tion%5D'],
    company_code: result['ny_code%5D'],
    division_code: result['rt%5Bdivision_code%5D']
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    drawChart(data.idCompleted, data.idPending, data.idStarted);
updatebackground($(this),textStatus, color, colorArray); // call function here
  },
});
```

move all code to a seperate funtion:

```
funtion updatebackground(element,textStatus, color, colorArray){
if (textStatus == 'SUCCESS' && color == undefined || color == colorArray.length) {

  element.css('background-color', colorArray[0]);
  element.data('color', '0');

} else if (textStatus == 'SUCCESS') {

  element.css('background-color', colorArray[color + 1]);
  element.data('color', color + 1);

}
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: is not possible the ajax is always inside a javascript function